# Removing the divider for (n-1)th item in an Expandable List View?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I would like to remove the divider for the last but one th item of a `ListView`.

`android:footerDividersEnabled="false"` removes the divider for the last item, but I want to remove divider for the item *above the last item*. How can I do this?

Comment: You remove the divider altogether and make your rows(with the exception of the n-1 row) to contain the divider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm solving this issue pragmatically by adding the following to my group layout

Put your group layout into a parent relative layout and then add this to this layout

```
    <View android:id="@+id/divider_view"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/your_divider"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/parent_layout_id"/>
```

Then in your adapter `getGroupView()`
add the following

```
if(groupPosition == mGrouplist.size() -1)
{
    dividerView.setVisibilty(View.GONE)
}else
{
    dividerView.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE)
}
```